# How can I hide a parameter's defaultValue in Swagger UI?

Tags: ruby, swagger

I place the Swagger formatting directly in my Ruby API source and use Source2Swagger to create the documentation:

```
# ~ a = my_api.apis.add
# ~ a.set :path => "/my_api/{application_key}"
# ~ op = a.operations.add
# ~ op.set :httpMethod => "GET", :nickname => "getmyapi"
# ~ op.summary = "Get stuff from My API"
# ~ op.parameters.add :name => "application_key", :description => "User authentication token", :dataType => "string", :allowMultiple => false, :required => false, :paramType => "path", :defaultValue => "1234567890"
# ~ op.responseMessages.add :message => "No stuff found", :code => 204
# ~ op.responseMessages.add :message => "API down", :code => 500
#
get '/my_api/?:application_key?', :provides => :json do
  Do stuff...
end
```

The "application_key" is not required, but users need to know the option when the API goes live.  As you can see above, I was asked to supply a default value for internal use (please don't ask why :-)) but I would still like to hide the default value of the parameter when displaying the documentation.  Is this possible?

Comment: sorry I have deleted my answer as I noticed you need it to work on swagger ui. (my answer was not in accordance with it)

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do it without hacking the UI. You'd need to find that specific operation and that specific parameter and override its behavior.

If you think about it, what you're asking doesn't make a lot of sense. You're saying that you're being asked to document something one way, but when displaying the documentation, you want to display it differently.

There are of course other possible solutions like proxying your documentation and changing it at the proxy, but that may be more work than it is worth.